# On Ubuntu: I deleted /usr/bin/python2.7 - please help

Tags: python, ubuntu

I accidentally overwrote my /usr/bin/python2.7 executable.  When I try to reinstall with

aptitude reinstall python2.7

It fails because, python2.7 is required to install python2.7.  I'm in a bind.  I do have python2.6 installed, but aptitude isn't work with that.

Anyideas?  I really just need to replace that executable, but I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Probably you need to reinstall some more basic package like `python2.7-minimal` or similar.  You can find out via `dpkg -S /usr/bin/python2.7` which package you need to reinstall.  Since I'm not using Ubuntu myself, I can't give a definite answer at the moment.

Comment: @Sven Marnach

You're exactly right.  On Ubuntu 11.04:

    `$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/python2.7`
    `python2.7-minimal: /usr/bin/python2.7`

@user475119 If you try aptitude install python2.7-minimal, does it work?

Comment: sudo dpkg -i python-minimal_2.7.1-0ubuntu5_all.deb and similar give..
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py", line 5, in <module>
        from _weakref import ref
    ImportError: No module named _weakref

Comment: @user: Try the following: move `python-minimal_2.7.1-0ubuntu5_all.deb` to an empty directory and call `dpkg -x python-minimal_2.7.1-0ubuntu5_all.deb .` in this directory.  This will unpack the package contents.  Then do `sudo cp -a usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/`.

Comment: tmp$ sudo cp -a usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/.
[sudo] password for gbc: 
cp: cannot stat `usr/bin/python2.7': No such file or directory

Comment: tmp$ ls

python-minimal_2.7.1-0ubuntu5_all.deb  usr

Comment: In usr/bin is a symlink to python like this ...  python -> python2.7 ... but there isn't a python2.7 file.

Comment: @user: You used the wrong package (and obviously I did not pay enough attention).  As stated in my and Jacinda's first comments, the `python2.7` binary is in the package `python2.7-minimal`.  You used `python-minimal` instead, which is an almost empty package with the sole purpose of selection the system's standard Python version.

Answer (score 6):

You can download the package needed from here:

http://packages.ubuntu.com/natty/python-minimal

then use dpkg to install it (I don't think it needs python to run):

`sudo dpkg -i python-minimal_2.7.1-0ubuntu5_all.deb`

If you are not running Ubuntu 11.04, you may need to download the correct version from packages.ubuntu.com for your version of Ubuntu. If so, then the filename of the .deb file will also change in the `dpkg` command.

Comment: Wouldn't `aptitude reinstall python2.7-minimal` be much easiser?

Comment: As the original poster mentioned, aptitude fails because it uses python, which was indeed overwritten, which was the problem in the first place. ;-)

Comment: @Victor: `aptitude reinstall python2.7` fails because `python2.7` depends on `python2.7-minimal`.  Aptitude doesn't depend on Python.

Comment: Oh I see... That's not what I interpreted it as saying. But why would it need python to install python. That doesn't make any sense. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: Interesting.  I basically overwrote /usr/bin/python2.7 with /usr/bin/python2.6 while trying to symlink and be distracted by the dog and the kids.   Getting import error when running dpkg, apt-get or aptitude with the various packages including minimal:  ImportError: No module named _weakref

Comment: @Victor: The package `python2.7` depends on the package `python2.7-minimal`, and the latter contains the actual Python interpreter.  Installing the package `python2.7` indeed requires `python27.-minimal` to be correctly installed.

Comment: @Sven: Right, but why doesn't `aptitude` in that case just reinstall `python2.7-minimal` when it is reinstalling `python2.7`? :\ Seems to be that it shouldn't fail just because of a package dependency.

Comment: @Victor: Aptitude would consider the package to be installed, because according to dpkg's database it *is* installed.  Aptitude's `reinstall` command only reinstalls the packages you explicitly tell it to reinstall, not all packages these packages depends on.

Answer (score 2):

[A similar problem](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6902170&postcount=16) was [resolved](http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=6904551&postcount=29) using the following commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get --fix-missing install
sudo apt-get clean all
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get clean all
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: Thanks.  You guys are so positive and helpful.  Thanks to all.

Comment: The first command here gives the import error:  ImportError: No module named _weakref.  I have a critical need for python2.6 on my system, and clearly one for 2.7, and the two things don't work with the other versions.  I think this problem was bound to happen at some point.  Going to rebuild/downgrade Ubuntu to the most recent that uses python2.6, Then my system will use just 2.6, and I should be good.  (For other projects that might need 2.7, I'll use virtualenv.)  Thanks again for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

did you look in /usr/bin? there maybe other versions of python (other executables) you could create a python2.7 symlink to

or copy the bin from another machine of the same arch.

Comment: I've checked my other machines, but don't have anything running Ubuntu 11.04, or with Python2.7.  I took backups regularly up to when I upgraded this system to 11.04.  I have basically, made it through a long career not totally hosing my system, and it looks like my good luck is catching up to me.

Comment: If you have the full GNU tool chain, you can compile python from source, and just copy the bin into the directory. Compile it on another machine if you have to; python is an easy build.