# Deleted /usr/bin/python* by mistake, how can I recover it?

Tags: python

By a slip of the keys I issued the command:

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python*
```

and with that the problems started. Python still starts, but when I now want to do anything with dpkg I get this error (entire error message not included as it is long):

```
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pydebug'
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/python-papyon_0.5.5-1ubuntu3.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

so basically papyon/pydebug or dpkg seems to be causing a problem. I have tried things like

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get --fix-missing install
```

following the same problem mentioned in another forum: [On Ubuntu: I deleted /usr/bin/python2.7 - please help](https://superuser.com/questions/292920/on-ubuntu-i-deleted-usr-bin-python2-7-please-help)

but to no avail. It seems no matter what I do with dpkg I get the same error. I naively tried to this:

```
sudo cp /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python
```

but that did not work.

Any help here would be appriciated.

Comment: lol unlucky....

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling Python and then re-installing it?

Comment: removing it as we speak. Since I am only on a 3G connection it will take a little time before I can see the results of the install. Cheers.

Comment: Nope not possible:
`Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's one hilarious slip of the fingers; I always like to use `sudo echo /path/to/files/*glob*` to see what files *specifically* I'm about to delete before I change the `echo` to `rm`. Now you've learned the lesson too! Fun.

Preaching aside, this shouldn't be too hard to fix, but it will take a few "passes". `deb` packages are `ar(1)` packages, and can be easily manipulated with `ar(1)`:

```
$ ar xv /var/cache/apt/archives/python-papyon_0.5.5-1ubuntu1.3_all.deb
x - debian-binary
x - control.tar.gz
x - data.tar.gz
```

Try this:

```
mkdir /tmp/fixing_python
cd /tmp/fixing_python
ar xv /var/cache/apt/archives/<package_for_overwriting>
cd /
tar zxvf /tmp/fixing_python/data.tar.gz
```

Iterate that for every package you need to "fix". `debsums(1)`'s `-c` command line option might be helpful, if you've got `debsums(1)` installed.

Note that the `tar` command there is a bit "destructive" -- it'll overwrite whatever it needs to. If you'd rather see what everything will unpack, skip the `cd /` step beforehand, and `tar(1)` will unpack into the directory instead, giving you a chance to see what is done.

Once you've got everything unpacked that you need, I'd try hard to get `dpkg(1)` "happy" again through its own mechanisms. (The `control.tar.gz` contains *control scripts* that are executed on upgrades, installs, uninstalls, etc. I just had you skip all of them, thinking that once you've got Python re-installed, you can use `dkpg(1)` itself to fix the problems.)

We surely have different packages installed, but this might be helpful for you in finding out which packages need fixing:

```
$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/python*
python-minimal: /usr/bin/python
python2.6-minimal: /usr/bin/python2.6
python2.7-minimal: /usr/bin/python2.7
python3-minimal: /usr/bin/python3
python3.2-minimal: /usr/bin/python3.2
python3.2-minimal: /usr/bin/python3.2mu
$
```

And note that you can pull down packages directly from the archives without using `apt-get(8)`. They're just HTTP sites and http://packages.debian.org or http://packages.ubuntu.com will make it easy to grab the packages you need with `wget(1)` or `curl(1)`.

**Update**

Oh yes, note that `/usr/lib/python*` is where the Python libraries and modules are kept. `/usr/bin/python*` is where the Python interpreter is kept. Your attempt to fix things with `cp /usr/lib/python2.7 /usr/bin/python2.7` didn't help. Also `/usr/lib/python2.7` is a *directory*, but `/usr/bin/python` should be (and was) a single executable file. Feel free to `rm -r /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/bin/python`.

Comment: By the way, `rm` has `-i`/`--interactive` option, you could use it too.

Comment: True, but `rm -i` gets old after four or five files.

Comment: The method worked great and fixed my dkpg issue. Thank you! I also removed my old fix (cautiously btw :))

Now there is the problem of the python package:

`>>> numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'numpy' is not defined`

I guess the PATH variable is wrong or something, cause dpkg tells me that numpy is installed. Do you know how I can have python in /usr/bin once again and also have the packages working?

Comment: If it helps:

`>>> print sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python27.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/plat-linux3', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-tk', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-old', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']`

Comment: @Paul: Are you just typing `numpy` at the prompt? Or `import numpy` at the prompt? You can't use plain `numpy` until you've imported the package.

Comment: `>>>python`

followed by `>>>import numpy`

Cheers.

Comment: Man, that one is digging deeper into Python than I've needed in a while. Something is definitely odd that your `sys.path` doesn't include any directories `/usr/lib/python*` -- try to reinstall `python-numpy` or `dpkg-reconfigure python2.7` to see if you can't "poke" whatever process left out the normal packaged directories.

Comment: Blue pill blue pill! I do not want to see how deep the Python rabbit hole goes. I want to wake up in my bed and believe whatever I want to believe. Thanks for your help @sarnold. The reconfiguring did not work. I will head down the reinstall path instead.